# Run JMeter Test in Jenkins with Parameters

Tags: jenkins

I have a JMeter test I would like to run in JMeter that have some parameters.  I installed the performance-plugin for Jenkins to enable JMeter testing as described here:

http://jenkinsci.github.io/performance-plugin/RunTests.html

However, the instruction is not clear on how to enter command-line parameters which is essential for my test.  Here is what I got so far:

[image]

Is it possible at all to enter parameters to run my test?  Or does it have to be completely parameter free.  IE, I need to hardcode all parameters into the test itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can easily trigger your JMeter jmx suite via jenkins coupled with performance plugin. For triggering the build:

- If you're using windows execute the build as windows batch command, giving the same commands that you would give if you were running your JMeter script from your command line.
- To give parameters you can conveniently select the option in jenkins configuration 'This project is parameterised' and pass the parameters ensuring the same reference is used in your JMeter jmx file.
- You can use the __P() function to make ramup, hostname or number of threads configurable and refer them using J command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this following command to run your performance test

```
jmeter -n -t GenericPerformanceScript.jmx > output.log &
```